# Class not found error when running on different computer

Tags: java

I am trying to run a Java application from the command line.
The format is as follows from the command line:
`<executable name> <configuration file path and name> -classpath <list of jars including the path to the jar> <path to main method>`

When I run this application, it starts fine and allows me to log into the application.  But when I submit my login credentials, I receive a 'Class not found' error.  My colleague can has the same jars on his computer and when he logs in it works fine.

We are using the same login credentials.

The jars are the same, so the class not found cannot be in those jars.  When it tries to authenticate, it uses a web service on a server.  So, I cannot determine where to look to see what class I am missing.

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I should be looking?

Comment: You seem to be missing the rest of the command you are running. All that is showing is `-classpath`.

Comment: Make sure those jars actually exist. I know you say you have the same jars as your colleague, but have you actually checked each jar in the list of jars to make sure it is in the location it is supposed to be?

Comment: "I receive a 'Class not found' error." post exact error message. Also `<path to main method>` should be `full.name.of.ClassContainingMainMethod`. Anyway it is hard to help without having [mcve].